# Binded control doesn't update on source change

Tags: c#, wpf

I bind this property

```cs
private string _attributeName = "";

public string AttributeName
{
    get => _attributeName;
    set
    {
        _attributeName = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
    }
}
```

with a `TextBox`

```xml
<TextBox Name="tbAttributeName" Text="{Binding ElementName=_this, Path=AttributeName}"/>
```

When I enter a text into this `TextBox` it changes AttributeName, but when I try to change AttributeName through CodeBehind the `TextBox` doesn't changes.

```cs
AttributeName = "name" //Won't change the TextBox.Text
```

Comment: What is `_this`? I'm guessing you either need to get rid of `ElementName` or change your path to `DataContext.AttributeName`.

Comment: `_this` is a `x:Name` of a `Window` where `TextBox` was placed.

Comment: Have you set the DataContext of the window to where `AttributeName` is?

Comment: No. AttributeName is in the CodeBehind of the `Window`.

Comment: Have you implemented the `INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface in the `Window` class?

Comment: Just in case it is not clear, you usually set the DataContext. However, if you use ElementName, Source or RelativeSource, it is not required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set **DataContext** to your window, you could do it in the constructor as following

```
 public MainWindow()
 {
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this; // set the code beind class to be the datacontext source for xaml
 }
```

and bind your Properties in the xaml as following

```
<TextBox Name="tbAttributeName" Text="{Binding AttributeName}"></TextBox>
```

### Update

make sure that your window implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged`
so the code behind will look like this

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window ,INotifyPropertyChanged // <<<<<<<<
 {
     public MainWindow()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
         DataContext = this; // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<
     }
     private string _attributeName = "";

     public string AttributeName
     {
         get => _attributeName;
         set
                         {
             _attributeName = value;
             OnPropertyChanged();
         }
     }

     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

     protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null)
     {
         PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
         if (handler != null)
         {
             handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
         }
     }

     private void btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
         AttributeName = "value changerd";

     }
 }
```

Comment: Make sure that your window implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface as the updated code

Comment: Yes, I forgot to implement the interface